# use of declare keyword on custom types

Tags: typescript

I'm confused about the concept of `Typescript` definition files. I have a project structure like this:

```
project/
├── src/
│   ├── models/
│       ├── Category.ts
│   ├── types/
│       ├── types.d.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
```

**src/models/Category.ts:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export class CategoryModel {

    async findAllCategories(): Promise<Category[]> {
        const data = await axios.get('/localhost:3000/api/categories');
        return data;
    }
}
```

All project types are written on `types/types.d.ts` file.

**src/types/types.d.ts:**

```
type PromiseResult<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T

type Category = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    slug: string;
    parent: number;
    image: string | null;
    count: number;
}
```

Code works fine but how `CategoryModel` file knows there is a custom type defined on `types.d.ts`.
I mean without importing a `types.d.ts` file on the `CategoryModel`. Why this line is not throwing an error?

```
async findAllCategories(): Promise<Category[]>
```

If I don't write the `declare` keyword on the custom types the code still works fine. But What is the difference between with or without `declare` keyword?

**src/types/types.d.ts:**

```
declare type PromiseResult<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T

declare type Category = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    slug: string;
    parent: number;
    image: string | null;
    count: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PromiseResult` and `Category` in `types.d.ts` are automatically added to the global scope, because there is no `import`/`export` statement at the file top-level.

Or in other words, they become global type declarations, as the file is not a module. And you don't have to `import` global declarations manually, they are implicitly known (like the TS `lib` types). To illustrate that, add `export {}` in `src/types/types.d.ts` to make it a module - now there will be an error triggered for `findAllCategories`.

Regarding the `declare`: You can just leave that keyword out. A `type` is always an ambient declaration, so it is kind of redundant.

Comment: Can you explain What is an ambient declaration?

Comment: An ambient declaration is just a declaration "without implementation" at run-time and is supposed to give the compiler additional hints for type checking. So, if you have a variable declartion `const x = 3`, you can make it ambient with `declare const x: number` and the compiler knows about it. A `type` itself is already ambient (stripped off at run-time), so `declare` doesn't have an effect here.